# What does "leave like" mean?

Tags: grammar

> The news left me like a fool.

What does it mean? Is the grammar ok here?

<sub>[Originally asked by birdman1234]</sub>

Comment: What **can not** be okay with grammar here? You probably mean the semantics, nothing about grammar.

Comment: The news could have been wiser in not leaving you in the first place, I understand.

Comment: Personally I don't like the phrase much, it is one of those darn idiom-like things that stick around, that really shouldn't have. I'd just come up something new. "The news made a fool out of me." Or if your twisting the phrase a bit, "The news left me like a love-struck fool." <--Note this is still ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the sentence immediately appears to be doing is likening the news to a fool, which is grammatically correct but semantically dubious.

Compare a similar sentence:

> The punch hit me like a bullet.

There is a large ellipsis — “would hit me” could be added to the end. But it is obvious that it is the punch which is being likened to a bullet, not *me.*

In order that what is after *like* refers to *me,* another verb needs to be added:

> The punch had me reeling like a drunkard.

Swapping the metaphors around makes nonsense, or at least, changes the meaning rather dramatically:

> The punch hit me like a drunkard.
>   The punch had me reeling like a bullet.

Now, one can mangle all sort of things with poetic licence<sup>1</sup>, and it’s just about possible to [grudgingly] accept that the original sentence might be likening *me* to a fool, simply because *news* cannot be: **that** makes no sense at all. The same applies to my last two sentences: with some effort, they can be untangled. But ideally there would be more context which established that form of language.

As a bare sentence on its own, in order to be semantically correct, it's grammatically dubious.

---

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps the [anapaestic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anapaest) rhythm in *like a fool* is necessary.

Comment: I do not see any of the suggestions have anything to do with the question

Comment: "What the sentence immediately appears to be doing is likening the news to a fool"

Comment: "The news left me like a fool would?" that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Exactly. That's what the answer explains.

Comment: But _The news left me flabbergasted_ or _The news left me (for) a fool_ does.

Comment: Yes. The insertion of *like* changes the sentence.

Comment: I had to look up anapaestic, an explanation or a link would have been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is semantically incorrect. Although used often, especially in song texts, the more correct version of your specific sentence would be without the "like" or with a word such as standing or feeling:

> The news left me ***a fool***
>
> The news left me ***standing/feeling like a fool***

[Merriam-Webster: leave](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave)

> to cause or allow to be or remain in a specified condition *leave the door open*, *his manner left me cold*

In your example

> The news left me ***flabbergasted***

I read your sentence as:

> When I got the news, it affected me so much, I was left looking/feeling like a fool.

Comment: This is true, but the *like* alters things.

Comment: I'd go for "feeling like a fool" I suppose you could *look* foolish but it's more likely you *feel* foolish or you *feel like a fool*. Might "The news left me feeling foolish" be more appropriate?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. Left with open mouth and snot running down the face. Astonishment as in flabbergasted goes with a certain look in my mind